# Kendo Ui AutoComplete - How to change default filter "startWith" to "contains"?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

My application built with AngularJs and KendoUI controls. I used AutoComplete Text Box so many places in the application. Now client wants that search should be with "Contains" filter. for the same i need to put filter: 'contains' everywhere AutoComplete control used.

I want to change default filter 'startWith' to 'contains' at beginning of the application. So that i can escape to make change every html file.

can anyone knows how to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to update your auto complete filter property at least once for all controls to support dynamic property binding and bind to some root configuration, like:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete k-filter="config.autoComplete.defaultFilter" />
```

So will be able to change default filter in future by updating only config value.

Another approach - is to override default "setOptions" behavior for "AutoComplete" component to use correct filter by default somewhere on app start:

```
var nativeSetOptions = window.kendo.ui.AutoComplete.prototype.setOptions;

window.kendo.ui.AutoComplete.prototype.setOptions = function(options) {
  options.filter = 'contains';
  nativeSetOptions.call(this, options);      
}
```

Comment: I am looking for second approach where overriding default filter. I written code which you given at beginning of one of the JS file but its not working for me.

Comment: Can you set debugger into this part? Is it executed when you open page with some autoComplete inside?

Comment: Thanks Friend... Its worked for me. I added following line. Please correct me if you find anything wrong in that.    window.kendo.ui.AutoComplete.prototype.options.filter = "contains";

Answer (score 1):

You can use k-options attribute:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="yourModel" k-data-source="yourDataSource" style="width: 100%;" k-options="autocompleteOptions"/>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.autocompleteOptions = {
   filter:"contains"
}
```